# List instance of semigroup mappeding respective pairs of elements

Tags: list, haskell, semigroup

I am looking for most common Haskell library that introduces `[a]` wrapper that instantiates `Semigroup` by delegating `mappend`ing to its elements in the similar way to:

```
newtype SList a = SList { slist :: [a] } 

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (SList a) where
    l1 <> l2 = SList $ foldl1 (<>) <$> transpose [slist l1, slist l2]
```

For example, `SList [a,b,c] <> SList [d,e,f,g]` would evaluate to `SList [a <> d, 
b <> e, c <> f, g]`.

To my surprise I couldn't found any in Prelude nor other most popular libraries. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Not a wrapper type, but a different function that does that on regular lists: [`salign` from semialign's Data.Semialign](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semialign-1.1/docs/Data-Semialign.html#v:salign). You can either call it directly or implement SList in terms of it:

```
import Data.Semialign (salign)
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (SList a) where
    SList l1 <> SList l2 = SList (salign l1 l2)
```